# Ensure the EditText is directly below the label using LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have the following XML code (partial for this example purposes):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp" >
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgVehicle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbCar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Car" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbTruck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Truck" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbCycle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motorcycle" />
    </RadioGroup>
            <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etToll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For smaller screen like Galaxy Nexus and Nexus One the layout comes out like this:
[image]

How do I fix it so the EditText is directly below the `#6` label as shown below (no matter what size the screen is):

[image]

Comment: First thing that comes in my mind is use table layout with two rows and two columns

Comment: How would I implement the desired result with that layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5. Vehicle type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgVehicle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbCar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Car" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbTruck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Truck" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbCycle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motorcycle" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6. Total amount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etToll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
    <tablelayout>
       <tablerow android:layout_weightsum="2">
       <textview android:layout_weight="1" android:text="4">
       <textview android:layout_weight="1" android:text="6">
    </tablerow>

    <tablerow android:layout_weightsum="2">
       <radiogroup android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- add radio buttons here -->
       </radiogroup>
       <edittext android:layout_weight="1" >
    </tablerow>

</tablelayout>
```

Comment: Where do i assign how much space of the screen it takes up? I just did an example and it's not working correctly.

Comment: what takes up space? i do not understand your question.

Comment: use weightsum=2 in tablerow and layoutweight=1 in each column elements (i.e textviews ,radiogroup , edittexts)

Comment: It's a longshot is there anyway to say if the screen size is small then to change the `layout_weight` to ensure its actually 50%?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance unfortunately I can only pick one answer and M-WaJeEh's code did the trick! Thanks again.